# Fastest Approach to check if Entity already Exists in Database?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity

At the moment I have something like this, to check if an Entity has already been added (simplified):

```
WinEveryBetBYeMiContext context = new WinEveryBetBYeMiContext();
string firstPlayerName = "R.Federer";
foreach (var player in context.Players)
{
       if (player.Name == firstPlayerName)
       {
            //Player already exists
       }
 }
```

But since there can be 100s of Players, this approach looks to me very bad and its also very slow..

I heard about LINQ TO SQL.. But I don't really know if its better, faster and more effective..
Maybe someone has a good way to check such things and could help me out.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to make this a bit more efficient and readable:

```
using System.Linq;

var firstPlayerName = "R.Federer";
var context = new WinEveryBetBYeMiContext();
var exists = context.Players.Any(x => x.Name == firstPlayerName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Players.Any(p => p.Name == firstPlayerName);
```